# PCA biplot vs separate score+loading plots

Tags: pca, biplot

In the context of PCA, is there any reason why the scores and loadings are put into a single plot, the biplot? Do they interact somehow or it is just a preference of just 1 plot over 2 plots?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [Researchgate](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Ehab_Mahdy/post/Can_you_please_help_me_interpret_these_biplots/attachment/59d621b779197b8077980161/AS%3A297914397151239%401448039735565/download/Biplot.pdf)

> The most basic property of a biplot is that the inner product of a row
>   (object) vector and a column (variable) vector in the plot is the best
>   approximation to the corresponding value in the table.